# How to change Listview default text color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How i could change the default text color of this `ListView`? default is black, i couldnt find a `"text color"` option under the properties window (visual studio).

```
   <ListView
        Name="LV"
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
        MouseDoubleClick="LV_MouseDoubleClick"
        ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="LV_ScrollChanged" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" Background="Black">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border
                                x:Name="Bd"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FFFF0080" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#FFFF0080" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:TraceEventElement Event="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I tried these options, none was able to change the text color:

```cs
            Foreground="Red"
            TextBlock.Foreground="Red"
            TextElement.Foreground="Red"
```

Comment: it is called Foreground

Comment: @ASh theres no Foreground https://i.imgur.com/QEYh7US.png

Comment: It depends on your `TraceEventElement`.

Comment: @emoacht i only have this: ` <local:TraceEventElement Event="{Binding}" />`

Comment: What is `TraceEventElement`? How you define it?

Comment: @emoacht i dont know c#, this listview is from a tool that i got on an git repo which i'm trying to change the listview default text color

Comment: `local:` indicates that class is in your project and there should be a `Style` or `Template` which is appied to that class. You are expected to include all such information in this question.

Comment: @emoacht here: https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy/blob/29f6ad4640a681bcd566105c20db80e71862e77e/WpfTraceSpy/MainWindow.xaml#L236

Comment: The text color is hardcoded `Brushes.Black` in https://github.com/smourier/TraceSpy/blob/537c9f3814af88de897ea8389de1ad4088c88207/WpfTraceSpy/TraceEventElement.cs.

Comment: @emoacht Thank you!!!! changing the brush color worked! can you make it as answer then i could close the question with it

Comment: Hardcoding is not good. I will show a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `TraceEventElement` class by adding `Foreground` dependency property by [DependencyProperty.AddOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.addowner) method and replacing hardcoded `Brushes.Black` with this `Foreground`.

```cs
public class TraceEventElement : FrameworkElement
{
    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
        TextElement.ForegroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TraceEventElement));

    ...
}
```

Then `TextElement.Foreground` at ListView level should work.